# Mismatch Type while passing function from parent component to child component in React Typescript even though they seem to have the same signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing a small app in react and I have separated the UI part of the app from other component. I have some state in my App.tsx that is an empty array and I want to ask the user for input in a children component named UI and use the input there to alter the array. In App.tsx I declared a function to addItem to the state and I have also defined the functional component of UI to accept a function. When trying to pass the function to App.tsx to UI.tsx I keep getting errors from typescript saying:

[image: Typescript Error]
This error is in my App.tsx file on line `<UI handleAddItem={addItem}/>`

Here is my code for the App.tsx file:

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  dependencyList: string[];
}

const starter: Props[] = [];
const [items, setItems] = useState(starter);

const addItem = (name: string, dependencyList: string[]) => {
  const listsCopy = { ...items };

  const item: Props = {
    name: name,
    dependencyList: dependencyList,
  };

  listsCopy.push(item);
  setItems(listsCopy);
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="UI">
        <h1>Add/Edit Item</h1>
        <UI handleAddItem={addItem} />
      </div>
      <div className="Visual">
        <h1>Graph Visualization</h1>
        <Graph></Graph>
      </div>
      <div className="NodeList">
        <h1>Item List</h1>
        <NodeList></NodeList>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my code for the UI.tsx file:

```
import "../styles/UI.css";

function UI(handleAddItem: (name: string, dependencyList: string[]) => void) {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
}

export default UI;
```

At first the function addItem in App.tsx had different definitions for the parameters, specifically
`({name, dependencyList}: Props)`
and I had a mismatch. To resolve this I redefined the Props Interface in the UI.tsx file and tried to define handleAddItem as:
`handleAddItem: ({name, dependencyList}:Props) => void`
but this didn't work. Now I am trying to simplify things by not using the interface definition in the function parameters and just declare them to be the primitive datatypes. I am still getting the issues and I am not sure why.
I have tried looking into other Stack overflow posts for possible solutions, but I can't seem to find any that addresses my problems. The typing of the functions seems to match but I don't know why Typescript is unhappy with the definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to solve this issue by declaring an interface with that has the typing of the function inside of the said interface. Then in my parameters for my functional component I just use the interface and typescript is happy that I gave it a type for my argument and I also get no errors. Specifically:

```js
interface Props {
  addItem: (name: string, dependencyList: string[]) => void;
}

function UI({ addItem }: Props) {
```

I hope this helps anybody that also had this problem.